# in_array returning false even though I can see the id in the array

Tags: php, arrays

Here is the array for `$catids = $_product->getCategoryIds();`:-

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "94"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "133"
}
```

If I then check if 133 is in the array, it returns false...

```
if (in_array($catids == 133)) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Is there something wrong with this syntax?

The below is the use case for what I am wanting to do...

(if the product is assigned to category id 133, then render this...)

```
<?php if (in_array($catids == 133)): ?>
    <div class="collect-item">
        <span class="text">
            <?php echo $this->__('Click & Collect') ?>
        </span>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Use 2 arguments, not a comparison.

Comment: Thanks, I can see what I should be doing... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using in_array incorrectly.

in_array accepts 2 parameters ( please see [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) )

Your code should read

`if in_array ( '133' , $catids) { //code here }`

Comment: I think this was the first answer (but not 100% certain), thanks, I figured what I should be doing after the first comment on my original question. Exactly as you answer. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `in_array` function wrong way.

In the PHP docs you can find description of this function:

```
bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )
```

In your case, you should call:

```
if(in_array('133', $catids))
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the manual for how to use `[in_Array()][1]`

Your usage should be something like:
    in_array(133, $catids)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
in_array($catids, '133', true)
```

Answer (score 0):

in_array receive as first parameter the element that you want to find into the array. In you case you are comparing an array with 133. The result will be false and false will be passed to in_array function.

To fix your issue you have to call in_array with 133 as first parameter and $catids as second one

```
<?php if (in_array(133,$catids)): ?>
```